# How to sort an array based on a values in different table in MS Excel?

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula

I want to first filter the loca1tion based on the condition given, sort the output based on rank and then display it horizontally (which can be done by transapose formula). I have done the filter part but my formula to sort based on the rank returns "value" error. Please show how can it be done.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a lookup like this:

```
=LET(filter,FILTER(Table3[Location],Table3[Quanitity]>6,),
TRANSPOSE(SORTBY(filter,XLOOKUP(filter,Table4[Location],Table4[Rank]),1)))
```

[image]